# No se ejecuta el método dispose()

Tags: java

Quiero utilizar el método `dispose()` al presionar el botón `btnSignIn` en caso de que el usuario sea válido, pero no se ejecuta.

¿Alguien sabe cçomo podría hacer funcionar este método?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setContentPane(new Login().panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setSize(300,400);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public Login() {
    btnSignIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(usuarioValido()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sesión Iniciada!!");
                dispose(); // tambien he probado con el this.dispose(); 
                hp.setContentPane(new HomePage().getPanelHP());
                hp.setSize(300,250);
                hp.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario NO válido");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Estás creando una instancia de `ActionListener` con el método `actionPerformed()` sobreescrito, por lo que `dispose()` se referirá a esa instancia incluso si usas `this`. La solución más sencilla es que tu clase implemente `ActionListener` y que sobreescribas `actionPerformed()` dentro de ella. De ese modo `dispose()` se referirá al `JFrame` en curso.

Comment: Un último detalle en el que acabo de caer. Entiendo que tu clase `Login` extiende de `JFrame`, ¿verdad?. ¿Podrías compartir la definición de la clase?

Comment: Hola Roman, solo necesitas llamar a ***`frame.dispose();`***.

Comment: @MarcePuente, tal y como se muestra en el código de ejemplo `frame` está definido en el ámbito estático de `main()` (en la clase que la contenga, podría ser diferente), por lo que no se puede acceder a ella desde `Login()`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, totalmente cierto maestro, se me escapó, entonces debería sacar la declaración de frame fuera del main, gracias por la corrección!!.

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando una instancia de `ActionListener` con el método `actionPerformed()` sobreescrito, por lo que `dispose()` se referirá a esa instancia incluso si usas `this`.

La solución más sencilla es que tu clase implemente `ActionListener` y que sobreescribas `actionPerformed()` dentro de ella. De ese modo `dispose()` se referirá al `JFrame` en curso y, gracias al polimorfismo, podrás indicar a tu propia clase como receptáculo de la acción mediante `this`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo (ejemplo con todo en una clase):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton btnSignIn;
    public JPanel panel;

    /* Ahora sobreescribimos el métodop que recibe la acción */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sesión Iniciada!!");
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }

    public Login(String title) {
        super(title);
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        btnSignIn = new JButton("Pulsa aquí");
        /* Nosotros mismos nos encargaremos de recibir el evento */
        btnSignIn.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(btnSignIn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Para este ejemplo Login es un JFrame */
        Login frame = new Login("Login");
        frame.setContentPane(frame.panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parto de la premisa, de que estamos en la clase ***`Login`***.
En el cuerpo de la clase, creo la variable `frame`, que luego instancio en el `main`, con el objeto de la clase, para evitar tener que hacer a `frame` estático, solo resta llamar a `frame.dispose` desde el `listener` del botón.

```
public class Login {

    JFrame frame;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Login logi = new Login();
        logi.frame = new JFrame("Login");
        logi.frame.setContentPane(new Login().panel);
        logi.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        logi.frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        logi.frame.setSize(300,400);
        logi.frame.pack();
        logi.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public Login() {
        btnSignIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(usuarioValido()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sesión Iniciada!!");
                    frame.dispose(); 
                    hp.setContentPane(new HomePage().getPanelHP());
                    hp.setSize(300,250);
                    hp.setVisible(true);
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario NO válido");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Nota: se puede hacer el JFrame estático, sin mayores problemas, pero si se quiere usarlo como propuse, hay que cambiar la instanciación de `Login`:

antes ->

```
Login lo = new Login();
```

ahora ->

```
Login.main( cadena );
```